# How to find location of .ashx files on server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxpro

**Background:** My employeer at my non-programming job knows that I am an undergraduate CS student with some experience in web development. He has severed ties with the previous web developer he hired after a sour experience, and he's paying me to make several changes to the site. One of these tasks is to take make a new form on the site that behaves similarly to a form that already exists, with some modifications. My major barrier is that the site was made using ASP.NET, which I have never used before, but after reading through some W3 tutorials, I was able to understand the existing form and the structure of its submission, and I'm fairly confident in my ability to duplicate it.

**Issue:** There's an important function call that I need to access and edit that takes place in a .ashx file that I cannot find on the server. The file is referenced as being located in ~/ajaxpro/Business,App_Code.ashx in the headers of the .aspx pages, and I can navigate to that page in my browser, but there is no actual /ajaxpro/ folder on the server. From what I could glean from Google searches, I guess this may have something to do with this code in Web.config:

```
<location path="ajaxpro">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.ashx" type="AjaxPro.AjaxHandlerFactory,AjaxPro.2" />
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

But I've looked through all the other folders on the server, and can't locate any .ashx files at all. There is a Business.cs and an App_Code folder on the server, but I couldn't find any code that would relate to what's showing up on the ~/ajaxpro/Business,App_Code.ashx page. Not sure if this is part of my .NET naiveté, or what, but I'd like to know if it's possible to locate and access these files.

**Question:** Is there any way for me to locate this .ashx file so that I can edit it, and if so, how would I want to go about discovering its actual location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASHX file doesn't actually exists on the file system.

The config section you have listed tells IIS to process any request for *.ashx extension under the ajaxpro directory using the assembly AjaxPro2.

Basically the Ajaxpro2 assembly contains a handler that decides what it needs to output, in the case above the Factory Class **AjaxHandlerFactory** will handle all responses.

The short answer is you can't edit the output for the ASHX file without access to the AjaxPro2 assembly code.

Comment: That makes sense. So this means that if I have AjaxPro2 as a .dll, I'm out of luck, correct?

Comment: AjaxPro2 might be offered as a product which you could download and they might provide the source code. but outside that im afraid you will be out of luck